# How to feed multiple instagram images on website (no wordpress)

Tags: instagram

We are using below code to feed multiple images on website but no feed is displaying on website. So what is missing in below code? Please let me know. It is personal website and not a wordpress website.

Thank you,

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #insta-wrap
  {
  width:1280px;
  height:600px;
  margin:35px auto 0 auto;
  }
</style>
<script src="./includes/instafeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: "user",
    userId: 'bharatahir70',
    accessToken: '1557013702.1677ed0.b84d103aa57f42a0ae6be066bb0d58f4'
    target: 'instafeed',
    clientId: "521f60894abf4e1b8d73f5a260ae6079"
  });
  feed.run();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="insta-wrap">
            <h1>INSTAGRAM FEED</h1>
            <div id="Instafeed"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have debug your access token. Your clientId isn't approved by instagram to access user information.

> {"meta": {"error_message": "This client has not been approved to
>   access this resource.", "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
>   "code": 400}}

Also when you visit the page where this widget is installed, you should see error message in your browser console.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helped me very much but still there is minor issue.I am getting this message in browser console. "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead." But I am unable to find this function anywhere in my code as well as instafeed.min.js ... Where can I find this function? Please let me know.

Comment: Note: I also included the jquery-1.11.1.min.js file in my code and I am not even able to find above function in that file too. Ty

Comment: getPreventDefault is jquery function that's all I know. If you find in jquery source then I think you should get any of these two methods.

Comment: there is no jquery on my page. after this error / warning arrived, i had included external jquery to solve this warning / error. but this is not working. and the external jquery that i had included has already defaultPrevented instead of getPreventDefault(). and js that i used for instagram (instafeed.min.js) has none of the both functions and none of that functions are used in my page script.